# how do you freeze an ocean to get a desert planet?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, climate, astronomy

So I'm in the middle of writing my desert planet, let's call it Thermos for now, and I'm having a bit of trouble balancing some aspects which I'll get to later. Thermos is an earth like planet with an axis tilted in such a way that most of the planet is desert-like at its equator but the poles are frozen. This could be achieved by having the planet tidally locked or without rotation but that would make it uninhabitable. Instead the tilt of the planet is lower than that of earths under 23.5 degrees. Possibly this would allow icecaps to form on both poles and reduce the oceans making a mostly dry planet.

Now onto the later part: Thermos has to be within habitable temperature ranges. The concept was to have life adapted to the hot and cold regions, and since this is for a story there are humans living on this planet. Story wise Thermos was once covered by oceans but has devolved into its current state, with most water turned into ice which lowered the sea levels considerably. This question is a continuation of [what would cause oceans to disappear?]

**Long story short how many degrees should the axis tilt be to get the desired result? Would it work?**

Comment: The question is based on several misconceptions.  Deserts are not really the result of axial tilt: they're the result of circulation patterns and geographic barriers. For instance, a lot of desert is immediately downwind of mountain ranges.  ("Rain shadow")  Likewise, not all deserts are hot: the US Great Basin and the deserts of Central Asia are in temperate regions.  Antarctica is also a desert.

Comment: desert does not mean hot, many deserts are cold, desert refers to the amount of precipitation.

Comment: That’s not what’s being asked. I suggest rereading the question. The tilt of the planet mainly serves to freeze water at the poles to get a dry and arid equator. I edited the question to get rid of the misleading parts. If you have further criticism feel free to edit the question.

Comment: The problem is that things just don't work the way you seem to be assuming they do.  To get maximal freezing at the poles, you'd want 0 tilt, to eliminate seasonal thaws.  But the only way to get an actual desert planet (rather than a planet with occasional deserts, like Earth) is to have much less water in the first place: something like Mars, but with higher gravity to hold an atmosphere.

Comment: @jamesqf You just missed a good opportunity to answer the question.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer. Could we please have an instruction manual on how physics work in your universe, especially physics as pertaining to thermodynamic and weather. The few facts given clearly show that the laws of physics there do not align with what we are used to here.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR: But the point I've been trying to make is that I can't answer THIS question, because it's the wrong question.  You need to ask something like "How do I make a habitable planet that's mostly desert?"  Reading about the history of Mars would give you some clues.

Comment: @jamesqf Mars lost its atmosphere and it’s oceans due to loss of air pressure, making it a bad example of how to make a desert planet. You know what? I’ll change the question to “how do you freeze an ocean to get a desert planet?”

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR: But if you take Mars, sometime between the Noachian Era and now there could have been a time where there was still an Earth-pressure atmosphere and some water.  I don't think you can get a desert planet by freezing, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to build a habitable desert planet, maybe.  Mostly speculation, since I'm far from being an expert*.

The fundamental problem here is that in order to have a breathable-by-humans atmosphere, you need photosynthetic life to generate atmospheric oxygen. (Since oxygen is highly reactive, it needs to be continually regenerated, too.  See "carbon cycle".) Life as we know it needs water to exist.  Even the most highly desert-adapted plants need water, and indeed, many of their adaptations are for obtaining and conserving the limited water in their environment.

Furthermore, in order for life to originate in the first place, you probably need an ocean environment.  It's also arguable that you need some oceans to act as a CO2 sink over geologic time (limestone & chalk), and as a regulator in the shorter term.  So your planet must have some ocean, or at least have had them in the past.

Another reason you need water is for plate tectonics to happen, which might well be necessary for habitability - think of volcanos adding all sorts of stuff to the atmosphere, and the ocean crust being continually recycled by subduction.

The bottom line here is that you're just not going to get a habitable planet that's entirely desert.  You'll have to settle for one that's mostly desert.

So you have a planet that's midway between Mars & Earth, say 70-80% of Earth's mass, and similar composition, with a molten iron core to give you a protective magnetosphere.  It either started out with less water than Earth, and/or lost much of it over the eons.  It has active plate tectonics, and so mostly granitic continents and basaltic ocean beds. Oceans exist, but they occupy only trenches and the lower parts of what would be oceans** on Earth.

You still have evaporation from the oceans, and so rainfall and all the other weather that Earth has.  However, orography ensures that almost all
of the precipitation falls on the continental slopes (the area between the continental shelf and the deep ocean).  Very little reaches the continents.

So you have Earthlike continents that are desert, rimmed by wetter areas.  Your humans naturally inhabit the wetter areas (where they can grow food), but venture into the deserts for trade, mining, &c.  A Columbus on your world would use camels, not ships.

Now about those ice caps.  On present-day Earth, they're limited by the fact that ice flows, and when it reaches the ocean, chunks break off and float equator-wards, where they melt.  On your desert planet, the oceans are much lower, so this won't happen.  Instead, the ice will be more like that of Ice Age North America, flowing towards the equator until it reaches a balance with melting.  Thus your continents might have a number of meltwater rivers flowing through the desert.  (Like the Nile.)  There might even be occasional lakes that would be the equivalent of islands in the ocean.

*Here's a book by someone who is: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/principles-of-planetary-climate/5B5EEF0534CB6F69FB2E395DD21D3476

**Isn't it really an amazing coincidence that Earth's water fills the ocean beds so neatly, just barely lapping over the edges of the continental shelves?

Answer (score 1):

Simply have a large landmass, ideally even with mountains shading it from rain, to create deserts around the equator. If you want that area to be hot, you can also play with the planet's distance to its star or the star's heat output to increase average temperature slightly without getting rid of the polar caps. Axial tilt then only comes into play when thinking about your seasonal migration.

Answer (score 0):

Opening: *"Story wise Thermos was once covered by oceans but has devolved into its current state, with most water turned into ice"*

**There's a lot of water**

Available land mass will depend on sea level. Most water is frozen you say. Your planet has large, ice age like polar regions. In that case, the equatorial regions would become moderate rather than dry, because liquid oceans and clouds exist there. If you would introduce more summer and winter differences, by increasing the planet's tilt, more water would melt and freeze periodically, you'd get more water  circulation.. but you'd get no *deserts* completely devoid of water, or freezing oceans.

**Your ocean did not freeze, sea level went down**

One desert forming scenario I could think of: suppose as a result of some geological change involving shifting continental plates, erosion would cause  large holes in the planet's crust, that can gather liquid water. With each earthquake, oceans get deeper in these locations and sea level lowers.. sea will retract from the coast. In land hot zones will be the result. Circulation broken, land mass dries out. Eventually, deserts will form.

Comment: large cavities in the crust that gather water is exactly what earth has, we call them oceans. this can't lock water up.

Comment: Ok, removed the cavities.. Above scenario is based on lowering sea level. Whether the ocean gets deeper or water gets sucked up into cavities (or caves) does not really matter, the idea is to create more land mass by lowering sea level in the moderate zone.

Comment: how to do either of those is a bigger problem than getting rid of water. again holes in the crust is a great way o describe current oceans.